# Show layout bounds - custom views with custom color

Tags: android, debugging

We have a library of custom views that we use in our app and were wondering if there is a way to customize the color of "show layout bounds" from developer options so that views from our app are visually identifiable from other views.. any ideas?

Comment: Technically, no, you can't do that. Those colors are pretty much hard-coded in the `ViewGroup` and `View` classes. [`ViewGroup` handles the outlines and margin areas](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#4167), and [`View` handles the focus X and corners](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#22641). You could possibly override `onDebugDraw()` in `ViewGroup`, or get at `DEBUG_CORNERS_COLOR` in `View`, but the method is hidden and that field is package-private…

Comment: …so it'd require reflection or some other non-SDK access, and they've been cracking down on that stuff since Pie. Also, given that the outlines are drawn in `ViewGroup`, it's actually your custom `View`s' parents that would need modifying, which probably isn't a workable option in most cases.